# Linux memory usage utility written in Python

Tags: linux, python

Years ago I've been using great utility written in Python that shows per-process memory usage in Linux in a user-friendly format. Can't find it on google.

It added all the parts of the process that use memory like RSS etc and provided sorted list of processes by their memory use.